# Do typing judgements have a kind?

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, dependent-type, type-kinds

In Richard Eisenberg's [talk](https://youtu.be/bDdkeKr9vVw?t=25m1s) on his work with levity polymorphism for dependent Haskell, he clearly shows that this judgement / type is sound:

```
type Star = (* :: (* :: (* :: *)))
```

Does this mean that typing judgements themselves have kind `*`? Or is that more flexible, in that `*` *may* have a type of `*` **or** the returned... thing from `(* :: *)` (which I'm not sure of at this moment).

Given this assumption, that `(* :: *) :: *`, this would also mean that this type would be associative, too:

```
type Star = (((* :: *) :: *) :: *)
```

Which I don't think is correct. Could someone please clarify this for me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.  I think you've misinterpreted what is going on. `::` at the type level is like `::` at the value level.  Consider:

```
three :: Int
three = 3 :: (Int :: *)
```

This is just `3 :: Int` which is just `3`.  Already in Haskell + kind signatures you've been able to write: `(((Int :: *) :: *) :: *)` which is just the same as `Int`.  Or in plain Haskell 2010, `(((3 :: Int) :: Int) :: Int)`.  Before, you were limited to how far you could go in the "right associated" way because kinds didn't themselves have kinds.  The axiom `* :: *` changes that.

`::` means what it always meant.  I wouldn't view `::` as an operator that "returns" something.  It's just a piece of syntax that allows providing information to the type checker, but is otherwise irrelevant.  If you *really, really* want to view it as some kind of operator, it would behave like `const` albeit it would be difficult to write down what its "type" would be.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a typing judgment, but rather a type ascription. Generally the expression `foo :: bar` has value `foo` and type `bar` (provided the type-checker can produce a judgment that this is sound). As a direct consequence, saying `foo :: bar` has type `*` is flat incorrect unless `bar` is (semantically) equal to `*`. It is not possible so far as I know in Haskell or GHC to write an expression that reflects a typing judgment into a value, but if it were, its type would also certainly not be `*`.

Comment: Would the judgement itself be something like "how it has been (successfully) asserted that `foo` has a type `bar`", maybe an inference path or something? I thought I saw something like an inference stack in GHC 8.0 from [one of Chris Allen's tweets](https://twitter.com/bitemyapp/status/698424851455832064), but I'm not sure if I'm correct.

Comment: @AthanClark Right, a typing judgment would be a tree of typing rule applications which witnesses or proves that a given expression has a given type.